# Missing assemblies System.Net.Http.Primitives and System.Net.Http.Extensions.dll in build

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, dll, .net-assembly

I am trying to build a legacy .net 4 web application and although the build succeeds when trying to visit the site I get

```
        Could not load file or assembly 'System.Net.Http.Primitives' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)
```

or

```
        Could not load file or assembly 'System.Net.Http.Extensions' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)
```

I can manually add these files from backups and the site works but how can I get the to be part of the build output?

Nuget on the solution already includes "Microsoft.Net.Http.2.0.20710.0" and "System.Net.Http.2.0.20505.0" but neither of these include the missing dlls.

This needs to work on a separate build server so having hard coded paths for random dlls is a no-no.

The code is quite old and I cannot see any references anywhere in the code to either assembly.

there is one other Dll missing compared with the backups but I am unsure it is related "System.Web.ApplicationServices.dll" as no amount of Google turns up any Nuget packages that could contain it.

Comment: Is it a MVC 4 app? There is MVC4 msi which installs the bits under program file folder and GACs those assemblies. So you may want to check if your web server has installed that msi.  System.Web.ApplicationServices.dll is part of .Net framework.

Comment: When you deploy the application, are you deploying it over the top of a previously deployed site, or is it cleaned before deployment?

Comment: cleaned, just maintain the web.config

Answer (score 0):

1)Uninstalled Web API NuGet package.

2)Installed Web API (Beta) NuGet package again.

3)Verified that .csproj file contains for ALL referenced assemblies, so it will always take it from Bin folder,